# How to add Background Image in css using master page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, .net

Here i am using master page with three content page.I am trying to add background image in my master page content,its working fine in design time.while running my page the image doesn't appears.

Here is my css class code

```
    .Content
    {
        width: 101%;
        height: 600px;
        background-color:White;
        background-image:url('images/image.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: url('images/image.jpg'). Fiddle plase

Comment: Try background-image:url(../images/image.jpg);

Comment: @user3494471: are you uploaded images/image.jpg to server? Is images folder in the same directory as your stylesheet is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kartikeya and Neophyte said in the comments, this case might just be about the incorrect path you've set your background image to be searched for.

Try the

```
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
```

or place your image to the same folder where your html file is located, then try it. This way you can at least figure out if it's the path that's wrong here.